# Get left and right of member in sorted set

Tags: redis

I need to be able to get the members to the left and right of a given member in a sorted set.

For example:

```
["red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "black"]
```

If I asked for the members to the left and right of "blue" I would need to get back "green" and "yellow".

One way I could do that is use `zrank` to get the index of the member (let's call it x) of blue (2) and then use `zrange` with a `start` of x-1 and `stop` of x+1.

The problem: it's not atomic. If a member with an index <= x is removed in between the two steps (zrank and zrange) the indexes would not match and the wrong members would be returned.

Is there an atomic way to do this?

Comment: What do you use as SCORE, when add the objects to the set? If it is not used really, you may add items into the set with predefined score and use ZRANGEBYSCORE to get left/right subset

Comment: Good idea @Mimas but I'm using the score. If I wasn't, I'd use a normal set (non sorted) for performance reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use LUA scripting. Something like:

```
local rank = redis.call('zrank', KEYS[1], ARGV[1]);
if rank == nil then
    return nil
end  

if rank == 0 then
    return redis.call('zrange', KEYS[1], rank, rank + 1); 
end

return redis.call('zrange', KEYS[1], rank - 1, rank + 1);
```

There 1st arg is your sorted set key and 2nd arg is memeber in sorted set.

Comment: Looks like I'm really going to have to get into Lua scripting then. I was hoping to avoid it because I wanted to keep all the logic on the application side.

Comment: BTW, you can replace the call to ZCOUNT with a faster ZCARD

Comment: Counting is not necessary I believe because ZRANGE does not care if it is out of range.

Comment: OK @misterion I will code it into my app and try it out.

Comment: @misterion I tried it out on Redis 2.8.17 and got an error when using `let` on line 1. I changed it to `local` and everything worked in your script. Also, I made ARGV[1] into KEYS[1] and ARGV[2] into ARGV[1] as that is the convention Redis seems to want.